# Duration filter is ignored using FFMPEG Laravel

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

This commands works perfectly:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i flyer.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=1080:720 out.mp4
```

Trying to do the same with Laravel FFMPEG

```
FFMpeg::fromDisk('images')
    ->open('flyer.jpg')
    ->export()
    ->addFilter('-loop', 1)
    ->addFilter('-c:v', 'libx264')
    ->addFilter('-t', '15')
    ->addFilter('-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p')
    ->addFilter('-vf', 'scale=1080:720')
    ->save('timelapse.mp4');
```

Seems that all filters are correctly applied but "-t 15" is not.

The problem is that in order to work, the -loop parameter should be specified before the -i parameter.

This works:
`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i flyer.jpg -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 12 -vf [in]scale=1080:720 out.mp4`

This doesn't work:
`ffmpeg -i flyer.jpg -loop 1  -c:v libx264 -t 15 -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 12 -vf [in]scale=1080:720 out.mp4`

So I should I proceed with FFMPEG Laravel?
This topic was brought up in github:
https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg/issues/349

But no answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set input options not filters (or output options). Not knowing anything about PHP/Laravel, I suspect you need to use either [`openWithInputOptions()`](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg/blob/e6f93d8e3b1a917d6991a1747e0e5f73531f1e08/src/MediaOpener.php#L128) to open the input file or [`setInputOptions()`](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg/blob/e6f93d8e3b1a917d6991a1747e0e5f73531f1e08/src/Filesystem/HasInputOptions.php#L17) to set `-loop 1` input option.

Comment: Where should I set the setInputOptions()? I can't find that method.
FFMpeg::fromDisk('images')->setInputOptions() not available.

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with Laravel/PHP, so I don't know. But `setInputOptions` is defined as a part of a `trait HasInputOptions`. Can you inject this trait to your Disk object?